# bad request with UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking for some help connecting to this service and returning the xml.

Here are the instructions (from [here](http://www.belltimers.com/pdf/webrelayusermanual.pdf)):

> The state of the inputs and relays can be monitored by sending a
>   request to port 80 (or port specified in setup) for the XML page
>   state.xml. The relays can be controlled by sending GET requests to the
>   same page on port 80 (or port specified in setup). This can be
>   demonstrated by entering commands into the URL line of a web browser.
>
> Request the current state: http://"ip address"/state.xml
>
> ...
>
> If the control password is enabled in the WebRelay-DualTM  unit and
>   the state.xml page is requested through a browser, the browser will
>   prompt the user for the password. If the XML request is sent from
>   another application and not a browser, the html request will need to
>   contain the password encoded using the base 64 encoding scheme. The
>   html request header without the password looks like this:
>
> ```
> GET /state.xml?relay1State=1&noReply=1 HTTP/1.1 (Ends with two \r\n)
> ```
>
> The html request header with the password looks like this:
>
> ```
> GET /state.xml?relay1State=1&noReply=1 HTTP/1.1(\r\n here)
> Authorization: Basic bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ== (Ends with two \r\n)
> ```
>
> where `bm9uZTp3ZWJyZWxheQ==` is the base 64 encoded version of the
>   user name and password none:webrelay

Code:

```
function webRelay(){
  //working url http://75.65.130.27/state.xml

  var url = 'http://75.65.130.27/';

  var params = encodeURIComponent('state.xml');
  Logger.log(params);

  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic" + Utilities.base64Encode('none:webrelay')
  };

  var options =
   {
     "method" : "get",
     "headers" : headers
   };

  var state = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+params, options);

  Logger.log('1: '+state);
  Logger.log(parse(state));
}

function parse(txt) {
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, true);
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of coding errors that you can easily take care of:

1. In the Authorization header you need a space after "Basic".
   `Authorization : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username+':'+password)`
2. `urlFetchApp.fetch()` returns an HTTP Response object, so you need to extract the contents for parsing.
   `var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);`
   `var state = result.getContentText();`
3. You aren't returning anything from your `parse()` function.
4. You should check `result.getResponseCode()` after `.fetch()`, and handle errors before proceeding with parsing.

That said, I keep getting `Bad request: http://75.65.130.27/state.xml` errors, so something is still not right. This is an HTTP 400 response, and google's servers don't return anything to the script debugger to dig into it. You should check the username & password, although I'd expect a 401-Unauthorized response if they were wrong. I tried including a `payload` of `relay1State=2`, and got the same `Bad request` result. If you can capture the HTTP Request hitting your server, there may be a clue to what is malformed. This could also be the result of a firewall.

Once that's sorted, [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/XML_tutorial) should help with the XML Parsing.

Here's my edit of your code:

```
function webRelay(){
  var url = 'http://75.65.130.27/state.xml';
  var username = "none";
  var password = "webrelay";

  var headers =
  {
    Authorization : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username+':'+password)
  }

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers": headers
  };

  // Getting "bad request" here - check the username & password
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var state=result.getContentText(); 

  // You should check state.getResponseCode()

  Logger.log('1: '+state);
  Logger.log(parse(state));
}

function parse(txt) {
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt, true);
  return doc;                            // Return results
}
```

Comment: Question does the Authorization need " " or not? And I'm stuck too, I've reset the unit, tried changing the pword, still same result.  It's definitly getting to the unit cuz if you leave the username off it will return the 401 from it.  And last question what is the proper way to attach the payload.  var payload = {"?relay1State=":"2"} - Thanks Again this is helping

Comment: Auth needs space between `"Basic"` & encoded bit, I use `"Basic "`. Not needed around `':'`. Payload would be `var payload = { relay1State : "2" }`. Can you capture http packets coming to unit from apps-script cloud? (Port mirroring on switch / router? Wireshark?)

Comment: Mogs, Thanks for the help, I finally figured out the issue. The unit is actually receiving the commands, and you have to add the payload directly to the url.  But the unit it's self does not return headers, thats why we keep getting the bad request. Your code adjustments did help me create the connection, Thanks Again