# What headers to include in a UrlFetch / UrlFetchApp request when given a user ID?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've recently gotten credentials to pull from [this API](https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/technical-information.aspx) (CareerOneStop.org) and they sent me credentials that include an API token **and** a user ID. I have to admit that I'm a newbie when it comes to APIs, but I have used the [Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) method to successfully make a GET request from an API that only requires a secret token.

For example, this JavaScript successfully calls the Udemy API:

```js
function callUdemyInstructorAPI () {
  var baseUrl = 'https://www.udemy.com/instructor-api/v1/';
  var url = baseUrl + 'taught-courses/courses/?fields%5Bcourse%5D=@all&ordering=is_published';
  var params = {
  "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       'Authorization' : 'bearer authToken',
     }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
}
```

However, the particular CareerOneStop.org API issues users an ID also, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write a request function that integrates it.

It looks like someone had a [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675394/bad-request-with-urlfetchapp) on Stackoverflow, but they needed to provide a username and password, and I'm not sure that this ID / token authentication combination has the same needs.

Using what I've found in other places, I've built this function, but I get a 401 return:

```js
function apiTest(){
  var url = 'https://api.careeronestop.org/v1/occupation/I3ojbDKR1o97Veh/nurse/Y/0/10?datasettype=occ'; // this URL works, and you'll see that the user ID they give is part of the URL after occupation/
  var token = "secretToken";

  var headers =
  {
    Authorization : "Bearer " + token
  }

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers": headers
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var state = result.getContentText(); 
}
```

If you can give me any tips on formatting this API request, I'd be very grateful. I'n not sure what I need to do here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Davis! What the response text is saying when you get a 401 code? Add `muteHttpExceptions` parameter to options (set to `true`) and log the `result`. As a first possible solution - add `contentType` header set to `application/json`.

Comment: Have you tried building the URL manually before putting it into `UrlFetchApp.fetch` rather than building it with `(url, options)`? The endpoint for the oocupation endpoint is api.careeronestop.org/v1/occupation/{userId}/{keyword}/{location} as seen in the documentation here https://www.careeronestop.org/Developers/WebAPI/Occupation/get-occupation-details.aspx.

Comment: Hi Oleg and Rafa. Thanks--I'm going to use your tips to see if they enable me to get this working, then I'll update the question / comment!